# Web browser not firing Navigated and DocumentCompleted event

Tags: c#, winforms, web-controls

I am trying to load Url address to the WebControl to show on my form in WinForns project. this is a code:

```
WebBrowser webControl = new WebBrowser();
webControl.AllowNavigation = true;
webControl.Visible = true;
webControl.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
webControl.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

webControl.DocumentCompleted += (sender, args) =>
{
    ......
};

webControl.Navigated += (sender, args) =>
{
    ......
};

webControl.Navigating += (sender, args) =>
{
    .....
};

webControl.Navigate(url);
```

The event Navigating is fired, but Navigated and DocumentCompleted not. 
Application should show google translate page with translated text. I was trying this url address:

```
1) https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/Try+to+translate
```

What's wrong
Thanks for advice

Comment: Your code works. I'm using VS2015 with Win10. Navigating, Navigated, Navigating, Navigated, DocumentCompleted, DocumentCompleted in that order.

Comment: Really? I got breakpoints and events will not occur... :-/

Comment: I also use breakpoints and copy paste from your code. It works. (.NET 4.5.2)

Comment: It seems I have the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?